# Combining similar rows in Stata / python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, stata, networkx

I am doing some data prep for graph analysis and my data looks as follows.

```
country1   country2   pair      volume
USA         CHN       USA_CHN   10
CHN         USA       CHN_USA   5 
AFG         ALB       AFG_ALB   2
ALB         AFG       ALB_AFG   5
```

I would like to combine them such that

```
country1   country2   pair      volume
USA         CHN       USA_CHN   15
AFG         ALB       AFG_ALB   7
```

Is there a simple way for me to do so in Stata or python? I've tried making a duplicate dataframe and renamed the 'pair' as country2_country1, then merged them, and dropped duplicate volumes, but it's a hairy way of going about things: I was wondering if there is a better way.

If it helps to know, my data format is for a directed graph, and I am converting it to undirected.

Comment: you could create a "sorted" key with `sorted_pair = "_".join(sorted(pair.split("_")))` so the countries are always in the same order; To help you further, we'd need to see some code of yours.
`

Answer (score 3):

Your key must consist of **sets** of two countries, so that they compare equal regardless of order. In Python/Pandas, this can be accomplished as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

# load in your data
s = """
country1   country2   pair      volume
USA        CHN        USA_CHN   10
CHN        USA        CHN_USA   5
AFG        ALB        AFG_ALB   2
ALB        AFG        ALB_AFG   5
"""
data = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(s), sep='\s+')

# create your key (using frozenset instead of set, since frozenset is hashable)
key = data[['country1', 'country2']].apply(frozenset, 1)

# group by the key and aggregate using sum()
print(data.groupby(key).sum())
```

This results in

```
            volume
(CHN, USA)      15
(AFG, ALB)       7
```

which isn't exactly what you wanted, but you should be able to get it into the right shape from here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that takes pandas automatic alignment of indexes

```
df1 = df.set_index(['country1'])
df2 = df.set_index(['country2'])
df1['volume'] += df2['volume']
df1.reset_index().query('country1 > country2')

  country1 country2     pair  volume
0      USA      CHN  USA_CHN      15
3      ALB      AFG  ALB_AFG       7
```

Here is a solution based on @jean-françois-fabre comment.

```
split_sorted = df.pair.str.split('_').map(sorted)
df_switch = pd.concat([split_sorted.str[0], 
                       split_sorted.str[1], 
                       df['volume']], axis=1, keys=['country1', 'country2', 'volume'])
df_switch.groupby(['country1', 'country2'], as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
```

output

```
  country1 country2  volume
0      CHN      USA      15
1      AFG      ALB       7
```

Comment: Could actually simplify the second approach by doing `df[['country1', 'country2']] = df[['country1', 'country2']].apply(sorted, 1)`, after which the `groupby(...)` will work as needed.

Comment: Very nice. Didn't think about apply

Answer (score 1):

In Stata you can just lean on the fact that alphabetical ordering gives a distinct signature to each pair.

```
clear 

input str3 (country1   country2)  volume
    USA         CHN         10 
    CHN         USA          5 
    AFG         ALB          2
    ALB         AFG          5
end 

gen first = cond(country1 < country2, country1, country2) 
gen second = cond(country1 < country2, country2, country1) 
collapse (sum) volume, by(first second) 

list 

     +-------------------------+
     | first   second   volume |
     |-------------------------|
  1. |   AFG      ALB        7 |
  2. |   CHN      USA       15 |
     +-------------------------+
```

You can `merge` back with the original dataset if wished.

Documented and discussed [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0043)

NB: Presenting a clear data example is helpful. Presenting it as the code to `input` the data is even more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: As Nick Cox comments below, this solution gets a bit crazy when the number of countries is large. (With 200 countries, you need to accurately store a 200-bit number)*

Here's a neat way to do it using pure Stata.

I effectively convert the countries into binary "flags", making something like the following mapping:

```
AFG  0001
ALB  0010
CHN  0100
USA  1000
```

This is achieved by numbering each country as normal, then calculating `2^(country_number)`. When we then add these binary numbers, the result is a combination of the two "flags". For example,

```
AFG + CHN = 0101
CHN + AFG = 0101
```

Notice that it now doesn't make any difference which order the countries come in!

So we can now happily add the flags and `collapse` by the result, summing over `volume` as we go.

Here's the complete code (heavily commented so it looks much longer than it is!)

```stata
// Convert country names into numbers, storing the resulting
// name/number mapping in a label called "countries"
encode country1, generate(from_country) label(countries)
// Do it again for the other country, using the existing
// mappings where the countries already exist, and adding to the 
// existing mapping where they don't
encode country2, generate(to_country) label(countries)
// Add these numbers as if they were binary flags
// Thus CHN (3) + USA (4) becomes:
// 010 +
// 100
// ---
// 110
// This makes adding strings commutative and unique. This means that
// the new variable doesn't care which way round the countries are
// nor can it get confused by pairs of countries adding up to the same
// number.
generate bilateral = 2^from_country + 2^to_country
// The rest is easy. Collapse by the new summed variable
// taking (arbitrarily) the lowest of the from_countries
// and the highest of the to_countries
collapse (sum) volume (min) from_country (max) to_country, by(bilateral)
// Tell Stata that these new min and max countries still have the same
// label:
label values from_country "countries"
label values to_country "countries"
```

Comment: With say 200 distinct countries your maximum values of `bilateral` will be of the order of 2 raised to that power. You also need to hold that many distinct values without error. I wouldn't therefore recommend as you do tacitly the use of a `float` datatype. (Conversely, if you `set type double` as a default so that this never bites you, that's far from universal.) I like the clever trick here but I don't think this is the best way to do it.

Comment: @NickCox fair comment. I thought about doing this using columns to store each of the country flags, but it all got a bit tiresome.

Comment: Your edit doesn't capture the facts fairly. Stata can handle numbers that large; it's just not possible with the default default [repetition intended] variable type. Stata's line is that programmers may need to think about how variables should be held.

Comment: In that case I don't understand your objection. What does "far from universal" mean?

Comment: You can `set type double` as your own default (see `help generate`), but all the evidence I've seen in questions about variable types is that few people have noticed that and fewer do it.